# How to make KSH function return only some echo message

Tags: shell, unix, stdout, ksh

Suppose I have a KSH function that return the sum of its arguments, but if the arguments are not supplied, it prompts for user inputs:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sum() {
  typeset v1=$1
  typeset v2=$2

  test -z "$v1" && { printf "please enter v1: "; read v1; }
  test -z "$v2" && { printf "please enter v2: "; read v2; }

  echo $((v1+v2))
}
```

I would like to assign the result of this function to a variable, normally I would do it like this

```
typeset result=`sum 3 4`
echo $result # 7
```

But when I use the prompt version

```
typeset result=`sum`
echo $result
```

It has 2 undesired effect: first the prompt messages `please enter ...` do not display, second, the `result` will include the text `please enter ...` instead of just number.

```
$ typeset result=`sum`
$ 1
$ 2
$ echo $result
please enter v1: please enter v2: 3
```

**How can I edit the function `sum` such that when no arguments supplied, it print the prompt messages `please enter ...` to stdout instead of returning it the the `result` variable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have to express that prompting for input in the middle of a function like this is a terrible idea.  But if you're going to do it, you can either print the prompts to stderr or to /dev/tty

```
sum() {
  typeset v1=$1
  typeset v2=$2

  test -z "$v1" && { printf "please enter v1: " >&2; read v1; }
  test -z "$v2" && { printf "please enter v2: " > /dev/tty; read v2; }

  echo $((v1+v2))
}
```

Or, use `read -p` to have read print the prompt to stderr.  (that is `test -z "$v1" && read -p "Please enter v1: " v1`)

Comment: Your words hit me. I already experienced why it is terrible; your have to concern in most line of code whether it can prompt for inputs. So I keep your suggestion and trying to refactor the program to prompt for inputs only in portal functions.